# Why does it makes sense to have 2 compilation units the same package name?

Tags: java, package

I was reading Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in Java, 4th edition* and he introduced the concept of package and how they better follow the hierarchical structure of OS for ease of access and de-cluttering of class files.
Well, he says,

> Each compilation unit must have a name ending in .java, and inside the
>   compilation unit there can be a public class that must have the same
>   name as the file (including capitalization, but excluding the .java
>   file name extension). There can be only one public class in each
>   compilation unit; otherwise, the compiler will complain.

Now, it is possible to have several compilation units having the same package name(I tested it). But why does it make sense to have it this way? This way they aren't **insulated** from each other and when you compile them, all the class files are in 1 directory.

Comment: you are bit unclear/fuzzy? what you want to know?

Comment: @YoungHobbit For a compilation unit, there is a main class and support classes. But if 2 compilation units have the same package name, and you compile manually using javac commandline, all the classes will end up in the same directory but not all are logically associated with each other. So, why does it make sense for 2 compilation units to have the same package name?

Comment: @pulp_fiction Here's a Java project, https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/tree/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis , classes than belong together are placed in the same package. In Java, packages are the concept that allows you to group together (public) classes.

Comment: " In Java, packages are the concept that allows you to group together (public) classes."  BEST statement in context of my question. The confirmation with OS file structure of the package structure brought this confusion somewhat. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a compilation unit, there is a main class and support classes. But if 2 compilation units have the same package name, and you compile manually using javac commandline, all the classes will end up in the same directory but not all are logically associated with each other. So, why does it make sense for 2 compilation units to have the same package name?

When you have codebase (a set of class) which are related to each other, then only you put them into the same package. Otherwise always provide different package for classes which are providing a different functionality.

If you specify the same package name and compile them they will end up in the same directory, because that is how you have defined them. Java compiler does not check that whether all the classes with same package name are related or not. It is programmers choice, what classes he wants to put into the same package and what classes in different package.

You can take the example of java JDK code. All the classes related to input and output are put into `io` package, utility classes are put into `util` package, etc.

As per my understanding, when you are working on a large project, it is very important **how you name each of the class** and **how you organize them further in package hierarchy**.

Hope it will clear some air.

Comment: A very important point you have mentioned! Let me then assert, if you say this from practical perspective and this is being followed in all the production scenarios then, can I say that a package name is essentially equivalent to a compilation unit?

Comment: As much I understand, compilation units are class files not packages.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I asserted that from practical perspective.(What programmers actually do)

Comment: @pulp_fiction No, a package name is not equivalent to a compilation unit at all. There may be many associated classes in a package. *How* they are associated is based on convention, not necessity or the language spec. Looking at any non-trivial Java library or application will show this.